# Getting around UEFI boot loader to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, bootloader

I recently added a new 3TB hd to my rig, but when I tried to reinstall Ubuntu I started having problems with the stock UEFI bios/bootloader that came with my asus m5a97 motherboard. I remember facing this problem over a year ago, I ended up getting an older version of ubuntu to install fine, then upgrading to a current version....now I can't even get this to work.

Anybody? Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know how i would fix that, but try a bios update. http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3Plus/M5A97/#download